# VS code find xml attribute and replace with current value * factor

Tags: json, xml, visual-studio-code

I have to edit a large xml file and its contents and it would take me hours. So i was wondering if VS code or any other editor has a function where i could specify a field and multiply it by some value.

Comment: Notepad++ and its XML Tools Plugin support XSLT. XSLT will allow you to modify an input XML based on your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the extension [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen)

- select the field content (the number) in any way you like with Multi Cursor
- Start `Generate text based on regular Expression`
- for original regex type: `(\d+)` or `([\d.]+)` for floats
- for generator regex type: `{{=N[1]*3.1415}}` change factor for your factor, to limit the number of digit after the decimal point use `{{=N[1]*3.14159:fixed(4)}}`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as an XSLT transformation.

Or if it's a one-off, you could consider using the Saxon Gizmo tool. To increase all prices by 20%:

```
>java net.sf.saxon.Gizmo -s:source.xml
/>update //price with .*1.2
/>save source2.xml
/>quit
```

Further details at https://www.saxonica.com/documentation11/index.html#!gizmo